# XML transformation: Creating node in output xml from node attribute of input xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, transform

I have searched many sites to accomplish below requirement without success. Hope to get some hint here.

**I want to transform input XML in a particular format as shown below to output format, The attributes of a node from input XML is used as a node in output XML**

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<viewentries timestamp="20150429T170520,91Z" toplevelentries="19">
<viewentry position="18" unid="5952E3CE7079811485257DF8007535FF"
    noteid="10A36" siblings="19">
    <entrydata columnnumber="0" name="AssignedTo">
        <text>Nilesh</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="1" name="ProductType">
        <text>LOC</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="2" name="BranchNum">
        <text>1020</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="3" name="CustomeName">
        <text>OldDate ¥§ª¬®°, DiptiÃÝ D'Ál®°</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="4" name="ProductNum">
        <text>1234567</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="5" name="Coverage">
        <text>LIFE</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="6" name="DownloadDate">
        <text>02/26/2015 16:20:15</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="7" name="UWAssignDate">
        <text>04/15/2015</text>
    </entrydata>

</viewentry>
<viewentry position="19" unid="65280F1D19102E1285257E29007436E5"
    noteid="10E02" siblings="19">
    <entrydata columnnumber="0" name="AssignedTo">
        <text>Peter Coy</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="1" name="ProductType">
        <text>MTG</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="2" name="BranchNum">
        <text>1020</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="3" name="CustomeName">
        <text>DUPMERGENBMTG1, FLORANB1</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="4" name="ProductNum">
        <text>8880811</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="5" name="Coverage">
        <text>LIFE</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="6" name="DownloadDate">
        <text>04/16/2015 17:09:22</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="7" name="UWAssignDate">
        <text>04/16/2015</text>
    </entrydata>

</viewentry>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROOT>

<ROW>

    <ROWNUM>1</ROWNUM>

    <Assignedto>Nilesh</Assignedto>

    <PRODUCTTYPE>LOC</PRODUCTTYPE>

    <BRANCH>1020</BRANCH>


</ROW>

<ROW>

    <ROWNUM>2</ROWNUM>

    <Assignedto>Peter Coy</Assignedto>      

    <PRODUCTTYPE>MTG</PRODUCTTYPE>

    <BRANCH>1020</BRANCH>


</ROW>
<ROOT>
```

Comment: 1. I see no relation between your input and your output.  2. Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Please see the attributes of <entrydata columnnumber="0" name="AssignedTo">. The name attribute value is converted to a node

Comment: I see the value "76501" in your output, but it is not anywhere in your input. The value "MTG" is in the first record of the output, but in the input it's  in the second one. And I also don't see how "AssignedTo" turns into "-Not Assigned-". Don't make us guess.

Comment: Apology, I made it simple now.

Comment: Yes, it looks quite simple now. if you spend an hour or two doing an XSLT tutorial, you will be able to solve this and much more.

Comment: Yes, I am able to solve this.. Please see the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below xslt can be used to achieve the above requirement.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/viewentries">
    <xsl:for-each select="viewentry">
            <xsl:element name="ROW">
                <xsl:for-each select="entrydata">
                        <!-- &lt;<xsl:value-of select="@name" />&gt; -->



                        <xsl:variable name="assignedTo" select="'AssignedTo'"/>
                         <xsl:variable name="theSet" select="boolean(@name = $assignedTo)"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$theSet">
                        <AssignedTo><xsl:value-of select="text" /></AssignedTo>
                        </xsl:if>  

                        <xsl:variable name="productType" select="'ProductType'"/>
                         <xsl:variable name="theSet1" select="boolean(@name = $productType)"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$theSet1">
                        <ProductType><xsl:value-of select="text" /></ProductType>
                        </xsl:if>  

                        <xsl:variable name="BranchNum" select="'BranchNum'"/>
                         <xsl:variable name="theSet2" select="boolean(@name = $BranchNum)"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$theSet2">
                        <BranchNum><xsl:value-of select="text" /></BranchNum>
                        </xsl:if>  

                        <xsl:variable name="CustomeName" select="'CustomeName'"/>
                         <xsl:variable name="theSet3" select="boolean(@name = $CustomeName)"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$theSet3">
                        <CustomeName><xsl:value-of select="text" /></CustomeName>
                        </xsl:if>    


                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```